# Showing upcoming events (including todays event)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following loop that doesn't quite work. I want to only show upcoming events including events that are taking place today.

At the moment it shows all the upcoming posts but also the posts before todays date.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    <?php 
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $portfolioloop = new WP_Query(
    array(
    'post__not_in' => array(4269),
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'meta_key' => the_date(),
    'post_status' => 'future,publish',
    'post_type' => 'whatson',
    'exclude' => '4269',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array('key' => the_date(),
    'value' => $today,
    'compare' => '>=')
    ),
    )); ?>
    <?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>
    // content here.
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop.  ?>
```

---

I'll give this a go:

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '$today' ";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

                <?php 
                $query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post__not_in' => array(4269),
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                    'post_type' => 'whatson',
                    'exclude' => '4269',
                    'posts_per_page' => 20,
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                )); ?>
```

Comment: make sure you don't have empty recoreds in `meta_value`

Comment: `the_date()` only works inside the loop, so your meta_query array might be failing.

Comment: @andrewsi Ok... that's sounds like it could be the reason, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Rob - Is it maybe just `'date'`? I assume both references will need amending.

Comment: @andrewsi I've tried that but the list is the completely empty. This is the page I'm working on - http://www.wsd2013.com/whatson/

Comment: @Rob - oh-ho! There's a section on http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query about filtering on data parameters. It looks a little messy, but there are examples there. There's a snippet of code for "Return posts from the last 30 days" that looks like it should be very easy to adapt to what you need.

Comment: @andrewsi Just updated my question with what I'm about to try, thanks.

Comment: @Rob - good luck; though it looks like you might need to format the date as `('Y-m-d')`.

Comment: @andrewsi Ok thanks. Just gave it a go (added my loop to question as well), it's not showing all the future posts and is currently showing a post before todays date (which it shouldn't).

Comment: @Rob - you're going to have to combine both your queries. At the moment, you've got one WP_Query inside the add_filter and remove_filter calls; and then a second one into which you're passing your array of parameters. It's just that second one being run, I think.

Comment: @andrewsi Think I need to move everything into the functions rather than combining things perhaps? Really surprised no one has achieved this without plugins... but can see why!!

Comment: @Rob - I've added some code as an answer, as it really didn't work well in a comment box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
<?php 

function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
$where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date("Y-m-d") . "'";
return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post__not_in' => array(4269),
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
        'post_type' => 'whatson',
        'exclude' => '4269',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
?>
```

Comment: So this is without all the stuff in the functions file just to confirm? I tried it but it only showed a post on May 4th, so added `'post_status' => 'future,publish',`, which now shows all future and published posts. It seems it's not doing any kind of sorting on the date. Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: Actually, is that not comparing it to today's date?

Comment: Ah, for one thing, I messed up the date format; so I've edited it. This shouldn't need anything else for it to work. It's the value of the meta_query array that's important - you can add and remove the other parameters so you get what you need.

Comment: It should be checking that the post_date is on or after today's date. (I'm somewhat old-school, and tend to write SQL queries by hand....)

Comment: I still can't get it to work, still showing everything no matter the date.

Comment: Can you try adding `echo $query->request;` after running WP_Query? That'll print out the SQL it's generating and running.

Comment: (That trick will come in handy again, so thanks for that!) This is what it was showing `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (4269) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'whatson' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 20` Am I right in saying it's not running the date part?

Comment: Well, isn't that interesting. I wonder why it's not including the post_date meta_query stuff?

Comment: Ah-ha! It's because I need to put it in _another_ array. I've edited the answer again.

Comment: Ok had another go but no posts appeared, this was the query `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (4269) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'whatson' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'post_date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '2013-06-27') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 20` Seems very close!!!

Comment: Well. It looks like the meta_query array is for querying the post's metadata. I guess the clue there was in the name :D. But post_date is part of the posts table instead. Let's see....

Comment: k. I've tweaked the answer again. It looks like we do need to use the add_filter functions to put a more complex query together, if we're not accessing meta information.

Comment: Hmm, getting a few unexpected errors with putting that code in the functions.

Comment: What are the errors you get? I can't see anything too wrong with it - it's mainly cut and pasted from WordPress's docs.

Comment: This was happening earlier, every time I tried to put a query in the functions like that it caused an error. Specifically the last few brackets of the query, I've removed one bracket from the end as there was one too many but it's still saying the last bracket even though they all match up.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!!! Let me do a bit more checking but pretty sure it's worked!!!! Thanks very much for all the help, 2mins to check!

Comment: Ah yes; there was an issue with one extra bracket at the end of the array the `$query` line just needs two. Fixed in the answer - there's also a couple of commas that need removing.

Comment: Ok it looks like it's worked, it's broken my pagination so I think I have to take the pagination elements out of the functions.php query, run that query into another one, then that through the loop... I think!?

Comment: I think that's beyond my Wordpress skills. You should be getting a regular set of results back which can be processed in the loop by the standard pagination code, I think.

Comment: Another question I think! Thanks for all the help, very kind. Hope this helps all the other people looking for it.

Comment: You're welcome. I've learned a couple of things from this myself, too! I'll also recommend looking through the WordPress documentation, too - compared with most packages I've used, it's incredibly good.